# Print the input in hexadecimal

Tags: code-golf, hexadecimal

### Challenges

You need to do a program that outputs the input string to hexadecimal!

For each character in the input string, convert it's ascii value to hexadecimal and output it out.

### Example

```
Something = 536f6d657468696e67
```

Of course, this is code golf, so the shorter code wins!

Comment: See [Default input/output methods](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods). A file is allowed by default and there isn't much (if any) difference after this (apart from separating by spaces in the other question)

Comment: I'm downvoting because this question is too simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Pyth, 3 bytes

```
.Hz
```

[Pyth docs](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth/blob/d0857326708284d884298464363e633e1390b190/rev-doc.txt#L292):

```
.H <str>
  Converts A to a hexadecimal string, treating the string as a base 256 integer.
```

`z` is a variable autoinitialized to `input()`.

[Try it here.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.Hz&input=Something&debug=0)

Comment: 'That's what I get for writing a try-it link'

Comment: @muddyfish Hahaha. To be fair, you ninja'd my answer verbatim while I was writing an explanation on the last challenge :D

Answer (score 1):

### Bash, 6 bytes​​​​​​​​​​

```
xxd -p
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript ES6, 49 bytes

```
s=>s.replace(/./g,l=>l.charCodeAt().toString(16))
```

[Try it online](http://vihan.org/p/esfiddle/?code=f%3D%20s%3D%3Es.replace(%2F.%2Fg%2Cl%3D%3El.charCodeAt().toString(16))%0A%0Af(%22Something%22)%3B)

Comment: Wouldn't this replace newlines in the input with `a` instead of `0a`?

Comment: @Doorknob the OP hasn't specified that and `a` is the hexadecimal value of `10` (newline) so I'm not sure

Comment: Should it become necessary, `(l.charCodeAt()+256).toString(16).slice(1)` edges out `('0'+l.charCodeAt().toString(16)).slice(-2)` by one byte.

Answer (score 0):

### Python3 console, 21 bytes

```
input().encode("hex")

input() -- Gets the input in a string.
       .encode("hex") -- Encodes it to hexadecimal.
```

Doing this on the console saves the `print` argument.

Comment: If you do it on the console, it will print itself

Comment: You should mention, that this doesn't work in the recent Python versions 3.4 and 3.5. https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html#codec-handling-improvements

Answer (score 0):

## , 7 chars / 9 bytes

```
ïⓢ⒨⒞ⓧ)⨝
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter3.html?eval=false&input=Something&code=%C3%AF%E2%93%A2%E2%92%A8%E2%92%9E%E2%93%A7%29%E2%A8%9D)</kbd>

Explanation later.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript ES6, 50 bytes

```
s=>[for(c of s)c.charCodeAt().toString(16)].join``
```

Using an [array generator comprehension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Generator_comprehensions), it loops through each character of the string and generates an array of the transform, then call `.join()` with an empty string as an argument to prevent inclusion of commas in default array `toString()` method.

[Try it Online](http://vihan.org/p/esfiddle/?code=f%3Ds%3D%3E%5Bfor(c%20of%20s)c.charCodeAt().toString(16)%5D.join%60%60%0Af(%22Something%22))

<sub>This currently only works in Firefox v ≥ 30</sub>

Answer (score 0):

## TeaScript, 5 bytes

```
ΣcT16
```

I really need to add base conversion built-ins

[Try it online](http://vihan.org/p/teascript/#?code=%22%CE%A3cT16%22&inputs=%5B%22Something%22%5D&opts=%7B%22int%22:false,%22ar%22:false,%22debug%22:false%7D)

### Explanation

```
Σ    // Loop through input
 c   // Get char code
 T16 // To hexadecimal
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 25 bytes

```perl6
{lc [~] .ords».base(16)}
```

#### Usage:

```perl6
my &code = {lc [~] .ords».base(16)}

say code 'Something';
# 536f6d657468696e67
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python, 24 bytes

```
lambda x:x.encode("hex")
```

Test:

```
a=lambda x:x.encode("hex")
a("something")    # 736f6d657468696e67
a("Hello World!") # 48656c6c6f20576f726c6421
```